# bash: test return value of function in another file

Tags: bash, function, return-value

foo.sh :

```
bar() {
     return 1;
}
```

test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
if /path/to/foo.sh bar; then
      echo "success"
else
      echo "fail"
fi
```

It always returns "success" regardless of the return value of bar(). How can I make this works as intended?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`foo.sh` doesn't call the function; it just defines it. You need to first source the file, then treat `bar` like any other function.

```
. foo.sh
if bar; then
    echo success
else
    echo fail
fi
```